# JavaScript Multiple Entry Form Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery-form-validator

I am trying to use Javascript to validate user input before page redirects.
Users can either Input Student ID, Name, or Gender, and based on their input, they will be redirected to a URL.

However, I don't seem to get the multiple entries correctly in my javascript and nothing happened when the submit button is clicked.

I have tried different solutions which I found here.

see my JavaScript code below;

```js
var attempt = 3; // Variable to count number of attempts.
// Below function Executes on click of login button.
function validate(){
var username = document.getElementById("studentid").value;

if ( studentid == "12345" || studentid == "Daniel" || studentid == "Boy"){
alert ("Correct Input");
window.location = "https://www.google.com"; 
// Redirecting to other page.

return false;
}

else{
attempt --;// Decrementing by one.
alert("ATTENTION!\nInvalid student ID!\nNot associated with any student\nYou have left "+attempt+" attempt;");
// Disabling fields after 3 attempts.
if( attempt == 0){
document.getElementById("studentid").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
return false;
}
}
}
```

I have tried to use the solutions below;

```js
if ( studentid == "#12345, #Daniel, #Boy"));{
alert ("correct input");
window.location = "https://www.google.com"; 
// Redirecting to other page.


if ( studentid == '12345', 'Daniel', 'Boy'){
alert ("correct input");
window.location = "https://www.amazon.com"; 
// Redirecting to other page.
```

Comment: `if ( studentid == '12345', 'Daniel', 'Boy')` is not valid javascript. Try `['12345', 'Daniel', 'Boy'].includes(studentid)` instead!

Comment: You did not define studentid, instead you defined it as username and that's never called.

Comment: @jns that didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so many attempts, I finally got it right!

```js
var attempt = 3;
function check(form)
{
if(form.studentid.value == "12345" || form.studentid.value == "DANIEL" || form.studentid.value == "BOY")
  {
    window.location.replace('https://www.google.com')

return false;
}
 else
 {
   attempt --;// Decrementing by one.
alert("ATTENTION!\nInvalid student ID!\nNot associated with any student!\nYou have left "+attempt+" attempt;");
// Disabling fields after 3 attempts.
if( attempt == 0){
document.getElementById("studentid").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
return false;
}
}
}
```